# Existe diferença entre um Message Queue e um Task Schedule?

Tags: rabbitmq

Desejo fazer um sistema onde o usuario pode colocar para uma ação ser feita em algum momento.
por exemplo: faça X na quinta feira as 15 horas
e sei que oq estou fazendo é um Task Schedule, porém no caminho encontrei diversos termos que me deixaram confuso, como bibliotecas de Job Scheduler([Agendajs](https://github.com/agenda/agenda)), Message Queue([Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull)), Task Queue([Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)), e o termo Broker

Assim não sei se eles são formas diferente de fazer a mesma coisa, ou se realmente são coisas diferentes que tambem conseguem resolver esse problema

No final percebi que o Celery e o termo Broker são partes de um sistema de `MQ`

Comment: Job/task scheduler significa agendador de tarefas. Message Queue significa fila de Mensagens e o conceito é só armazenar mensagens ou arrays de bytes em uma fila e pegar do outro lado (ou distribuir de maneira espalhada para um conjunto de consumidores). Não sei se um usa o outro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um task/job schedule agenda tarefas, com regras de agendamento.

Uma infra de Message Queue, enfileira tarefas, sem agendamento. Está mais ligado à distribuição de tarefas com base na capacidade de consumo, enquanto um Job Scheduler está preocupado com o momento do agendamento.

Não é incomum você ver os 2 em conjunto. Um agendamento coloca uma mensagem em uma fila que por sua vez os workers irão operar aquilo no momento certo.

---

Se você quer um exemplo do mundo real, vamos supor que você tenha de fazer sua CNH ou qualquer documento em algum órgão do governo.

> O Job Scheduler seria um despachante, em que você combina com ele o momento em que ele fará o trabalho por você.

> O orgão tem uma "fila" de atendimento, que representa a forma como o processamento do seu documento será executado.

> Os funcionários envolvidos na emissão do documento, são os Workers que estão plugados no "message queue".

Tudo quem que esse é um exemplo que demora muito tempo, mas podemos trabalhar com outros:

**Ifood**

> Agendamento de pedido no app = Job Scheduler Chegou a hora, o pedido é
> enviado para a fila de atendimento = Queue Os funcionários do
> estabelecimento = Workers

**Banco**

> Agendamento de pagamento de boleto = Job Scheduler Chegou a hora de
> processar, o boleto é enviado para uma fila = Queue Um worker processa
> o pagamento